# KnockoutJs in ASP.net MVC4 with Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I am trying to convert my MVC application to use knockoutjs, I had this code on my view:

```
var itemsCount = 0;
<div class="boxes-container">
@foreach (ItemModel i in Model.Items)
{
   if (itemsCount >= Model.DisplayCount)
   {
      @Html.Raw("</div><div class='boxes-container'>")
      itemsCount = 0;
   }
   Html.RenderPartial("PartialItemView", i);
   itemsCount++;
}
</div>
```

Now, with knockout I have something like this

```
this.Items = ko.observableArray(tmp.Items); // [Object { field1="52", field2="56", arr=[1], more...},Object { field1="52", field2="56", arr=[1], more...},Object { field1="52", field2="56", arr=[1], more...}]
this.DisplayCount = ko.observable(tmp.DisplayCount) // 3
```

How can I update my first code with this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your view before closing body-tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // our model data

    var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));

    // start knockout

    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

Then you can use your model with knockout to iterate thru each item:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Items">
    ...
</div>
```

Make sure to add a reference to NewtonSoft.Json via package manager:

```
PM> install-package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comment: thanks, I already did that and Items has values, but inside the foreach I must do this   Html.RenderPartial("PartialItemView", i); where "i" is a model for the partial view which comes as an Item... ???

Comment: Ideally you should request the data in an AJAX request instead of embedding it in the page.

Comment: @b1tsh1ft could you explain why?

Comment: @RomanPushkin That way you have separated your Model (or data) from your view. (Separation of concerns). Also, if you have a server-side function that returns your Items, you could call that function from any page you like and re-use it wherever you like. And for performance reasons, now your page will take longer for the user to load. If the page didn't contain any data, loaded, and then did AJAX (which is asynchronous) it would create a faster user experience.

Comment: @b1tsh1ft how one more additional call can be faster? Keep in mind that it will be initiated only on document ready.

Separation of cencerns? Hm. It's not a model actually, this data is view model, so it's OK.